# My Get ( << ) doesn't work when path is in variable : why?

Tags: files-and-directories

Take this code :

```
    nomFichier = 
  "C:\\Users\\Me\\Dropbox\\testFile.wdx";

<<  nomFichier;
<<  "C:\\Users\\Me\\Dropbox\\testFile.wdx";
```

The first line works whereas the second one doesn't : why ?

The error is :

```
Get::noopen: Cannot open nomFichier.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

According to the documentation:

```
<<"name" is equivalent to <<name. The double quotes can be omitted if 
the name is of the form specified in "Operator Input Forms".
```

So, `<<` treats the literal expression as a file name.

```
Get[expression]
```

works, but the `<<` form even ignores `Evaluate`.

Comment: In fact I read it also but how to tell to mathematica use the value of the variable and not its name. Is it possible ?

Comment: @StarBucK See edit.